# Compare a column with a cell and return the values in front of that cell

Tags: excel

I want to compare column A values with another value and get the averages of the values in next cell.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUr6u.jpg)

Let's say I want the average of values in B column which the value of A column right next to them are between 0:10 and 0:25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the function, try:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,">0:10",A:A,"<0:25")
```